# Check whether three given integer values are in the range 50..99

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function to check 3 values.

If the 3 values are in the range 50..99, I return `true`, otherwise `false`.

In this example, normally the answer is `false`.

```
console.log(check_three_nums(65, 9, 199));
```

I have as answer `true`.

I don't understand, why?

```js
function check_three_nums(x, y, z) {

    if ((x >= 50 && x <= 99) || (y >= 50 && y <= 99) || (z >= 50 && z <= 99)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

// console.log(check_three_nums(50, 90, 99));
// console.log(check_three_nums(5, 9, 199));
// console.log(check_three_nums(65, 89, 199));
console.log(check_three_nums(65, 9, 199));
```

Comment: You use `||`, so only one of x,y or z has to be in the range. Use `&&` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to check any amount of number.

```
function check(...args) {
    for (let a of args) {
        if (a < 50 || a > 99)
            return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: this is faster than checking 3 numbers as it only fails if the first or second is false

Answer (score 1):

The double pipe operator (||) means OR, your function is currently returning true if at least one of the param is in your range.
Try to change it whith the '&&' operator
It should work as expected

```js
function check_three_nums(x, y, z) {

    if ((x >= 50 && x <= 99) && (y >= 50 && y <= 99) && (z >= 50 && z <= 99)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

// console.log(check_three_nums(50, 90, 99));
// console.log(check_three_nums(5, 9, 199));
// console.log(check_three_nums(65, 89, 199));
console.log(check_three_nums(65, 9, 199));
```

Answer (score 0):

"or operator" (||) will output true if one of the parameter values ​​is true (condition1 is true or condition2 is true). You can use the "and operator" (&&), this operator will only output true if both parameter values ​​are true (condition1 and condition2 are true)